# deluxetable* caption not displaying

Tags: tables, captions

I am trying to create a page-wide deluxetable using the two-column formatted ApJ article style. The caption displays when creating a single column deluxetable, but will not display when I use deluxetable*. I receive the following error:

> "Package ltcaption error: Not allowed in longtable* environment"

Here is my preamble and minimal compilable code:

```
\documentclass[apj]{emulateapj}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}

%Table 1: Non-working example
\begin{deluxetable*}{cc}
\tabletypesize{\footnotesize}
\tablewidth{0.99\textwidth}
\tablecaption{This caption does not display}
\tablehead{
\colhead{col 1$^{1}$} & 
\colhead{col 2} 
} 
\startdata
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\enddata
\tablenotetext{1}{Footnote}
\end{deluxetable*}

%Table 2: Working example
\begin{deluxetable}{cc}
\tabletypesize{\footnotesize}
\tablewidth{0.99\textwidth}
\tablecaption{This caption does display}
\tablehead{
\colhead{col 1$^{1}$} & 
\colhead{col 2} 
} 
\startdata
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\enddata
\tablenotetext{1}{Footnote}
\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't load those two packages with `emulateapj`. They are the source of error.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile your code, you get this warning from `caption` package

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

Hence you can't use `subcaption` package which is responsible for loading `caption` package. As a matter of fact, the subsequently loaded `ltcaption` package (by `caption`) defines `lontable*` command which is apparently defined by `emulateapj`.

Hence removing `\usepackage{subcaption}` should enable your code to compile.  However, the package `tablefootnote` starts giving warnings:

```
Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\begin' failed!
(etoolbox)                '\AtBeginEnvironment' will not work.


Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\end' failed!
(etoolbox)                '\AtEndEnvironment' will not work.


Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\end' failed!
(etoolbox)                '\AfterEndEnvironment' will not work.
```

`etoolbox` is used by `tablefootnote` BTW. To be on safer side don't use `tablefootnote` also.

```
\documentclass[apj]{emulateapj}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}

%Table 1: Non-working example
\begin{deluxetable*}{cc}
\tabletypesize{\footnotesize}
\tablewidth{0.99\textwidth}
\tablecaption{This caption does not display}
\tablehead{
\colhead{col 1$^{1}$} &
\colhead{col 2}
}
\startdata
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\enddata
\tablenotetext{1}{Footnote}
\end{deluxetable*}

%Table 2: Working example
\begin{deluxetable}{cc}
\tabletypesize{\footnotesize}
\tablewidth{0.99\textwidth}
\tablecaption{This caption does display}
\tablehead{
\colhead{col 1$^{1}$} &
\colhead{col 2}
}
\startdata
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\enddata
\tablenotetext{1}{Footnote}
\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

[image]